# Drop items into specific group in a listview

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to **drag an item between two Groups** in *the same* ListView called 'listTasks'.

```
Private Sub listTasks_ItemDrag(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ItemDragEventArgs) Handles listTasks.ItemDrag
    listTasks.DoDragDrop(listTasks.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Move)
End Sub

Private Sub listTasks_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles listTasks.DragEnter
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
End Sub

Private Sub listTasks_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles listTasks.DragDrop
    ' how do I tell what group is being dropped into?
End Sub
```

(note that `listTasks_DragEnter` ignores DataFormat checks to simplify example)

With `listTasks.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))` you could use `listTasks.GetItemAt(p.X, p.Y)` to get the ListView item you're over. Is there something like this for Groups? Or perhaps a better way to determine what group is the target of a drag-drop?

Comment: Did you try MSDN first? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289508%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Jasaph: thank you for the link, but there's no mention of Groups. I know how to drag-drop. Just after a way to drop into a different Group in the same ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
Private lviDraggedItem As ListViewItem

Private Sub ListView1_DragEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DragEnter
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DragDrop

    Dim htInfo As ListViewHitTestInfo = ListView1.HitTest(ListView1.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y)))

    Dim lviSibling As ListViewItem = htInfo.Item

    Dim lvgGroup As ListViewGroup = lviSibling.Group

    lvgGroup.Items.Add(lviDraggedItem)

    lviDraggedItem = Nothing


End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_ItemDrag(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemDragEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDrag

    lviDraggedItem = e.Item
    ListView1.DoDragDrop(ListView1.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Move)


End Sub
```

You will probably want to do some more work to place it at a specific place in the group, but this should get you started.